# ADB device list is empty

Tags: android, adb

I have the latest version of Android Studio and an Android device.

I turned on developer mode on my device and plugged it to my lap top via USB.
I didn't get the prompt message that asks me to authorize USB debugging with this pc and also my device list was empty when I ran on the cmd `adb devices`.

I tried to do `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` but the devices list was still empty and I still didn't got any authorize usb debugging message on my phone.

I tried to restart phone + PC + change USB cable but nothing.

Comment: are you on linux?

Comment: no, on windows.

Comment: @TK52 tried that, still not working.

Comment: duplicate sure, but jesus that other thread is a mess. this q&a is exactly what you need if you're downloading google's drivers and trying to install them on windows 10.

Comment: In my case usb debugging was not on.

Comment: Developer options + USB debugging need to be turned on, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211161/293064

Answer (score 46):

This helped me at the end:

Quick guide:

- Download [Google USB Driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
- Connect your device with Android Debugging enabled to your PC
- Open Device Manager of Windows from System Properties.
- Your device should appear under `Other devices` listed as something like
  `Android ADB Interface` or 'Android Phone' or similar. Right-click that and
  click on `Update Driver Software...`
- Select `Browse my computer for driver software`
- Select `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`
- Double-click `Show all devices`
- Press the `Have disk` button
- Browse and navigate to [wherever your SDK has been installed]\google-usb_driver and select android_winusb.inf
- Select `Android ADB Interface` from the list of device types.
- Press the `Yes` button
- Press the `Install` button
- Press the `Close` button

Now you've got the ADB driver set up correctly. Reconnect your device if it
doesn't recognize it already.

Comment: After trying almost all the options here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767810/running-phonegap-on-device-no-device-found), this worked for me

Comment: I followed these steps mentioned above, worked for me. The only difference in my case was the path of the `android_winusb.inf` file which in my case was, `AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Comment: and the usb driver has to be downloaded from the SDKManager first

Comment: I make the mistake of enabling developer mode Android debugging while the phone was connected to my PC over USB. I had to unplug and replug it to get the new device driver to be detected. It shows up as `ADB Interface` in my device manager.

Comment: Why is this not in the google docs?

Comment: 'Show all devices' and 'Have disk' is really important indeed. If you just stop at the previous step and give the path, it won't work : "No driver found" or something like that. That was ... tricky!

Comment: Step 2 (Connect your device with Android Debugging enabled to your PC) was important for me:

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Select System.
3. Scroll to the bottom and select About phone.
4. Scroll to the bottom and tap Build number 7 times.
5. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options near the bottom.
6. Scroll down and enable USB debugging.

Comment: It does not show up in under Other devices or anywhere in Device Manager for me. I've tried multiple devices, multiple cables, multiple USB ports, downloaded the driver, enabled USB debugging, change mode to PTP and MTP, restarted computer and device. Nothing happens when I plug in any android device except that it's charging now.